# Why is my shell script putting arbitrary numbers in this file?

Tags: linux, shell

I have a shell script given below:

```
gfortran -o perm_field.exe perm_field.f90
gfortran -o creat_fehm_input.exe creat_fehm_input.f90
gfortran -o wt_concen.exe  wt_concen.f90
gfortran -o statistical_analysis.exe  statistical_analysis.f90 /usr/lib64/liblapack.so -llapack
#gfortran -o state_write.exe state_write.f90
#gfortran -o creat_ini.exe creat_ini.f90

nsim=8
echo $nsim > nsim.dat
rm kalman_index.dat
rm random_log_perm.dat
rm random_log_perm_initial.dat
rm water_table.dat


for j in {1..3} ; do
    echo $j > kalman_index.dat
    ./creat_fehm_input.exe

    for i in `seq 1 $nsim` ; do
        echo $i
        echo $i > isim.dat
        ./perm_field.exe
        ./xfehm_v3.00intl64
        sed '1d' unsat_flow..00002_sca_node.dat > test
        mv test scalar.dat
        ./wt_concen.exe
    done
    cp Measurement_25/Direct/meas_s$j.dat meas_s.dat
    #cp meas_s$j.dat meas_s.dat
    #./statistical_analysis.exe
    ./calc_wt.R
    mv water_table.dat water_table$j.dat
    cp random_log_perm_updated.dat random_log_perm$j.dat
    cp random_log_perm_updated.dat random_log_perm.dat
done
```

In the line where I save

echo $nsim > nsim.dat

It also adds some arbitrary numbers in the later iterations. Because of this my whole program isn't working.

Example, after 8th iteration

```
$ cat nsim.dat
8
 -0.17957768183441541       0.95266884236814386
```

It should only contain 8

edit: I checked the output of lsof |grep nsim and only this script is changing nsim.dat, so no other program is doing anything.

Comment: Where's the rest of the script? The shebang line at the top? Which shell? What OS version?

Comment: This is the whole script. I am running it in centos 6.5

Comment: Have you got some symbolic links in your directory? `ls -l | grep "^l"`

Comment: The script by itself does no such thing. Maybe one of the tools you are calling is modifying the file after you write it?

Comment: That command is not showing any output

Comment: You don't use `nsim.dat` anywhere in here so how can this be making your program not work?

Comment: @triplee I checked it with lsof, it doesn't show any other program changing anything

Comment: @Etan A fortran or R program reads from that file. But it's not changing that file.

Comment: I'm going to bet that it does despite your assertion to the contrary. How are you checking with lsof? Spot checking won't help if you don't catch the process actually having the file open (which it may do only very briefly). Check the `stat` output for the file right after you write to it and at various points through the rest of the script. Or set it immutable/unwritable and see what command breaks.

Comment: Etan okay. But I also checked all the programs many times. All they do is read from that file, with the same command I use with isim.dat or kalman_index.dat, but nothing happens to those files.

Comment: You'd need to run `lsof` at exactly the right time to capture  something like this. `tail --follow=name nsim.dat & bash -x ./script` would show you exactly when the file changes.

Comment: As an aside, you surely don't want to compile your code every time you run your simulation. Try putting the compilations into a Makefile. You should also add a shebang showing the shell that you are targeting. Also, try indenting your loops - it helps readability - a lot.

Comment: +1 for making the file immutable/unwritable and looking for error messages. You can additionally `strace -f` the entire script, and also check for hard or soft links to this file.

Comment: @triplee I am doing that. I'll update if I get something

Comment: I agree with tripleee, `bash -x` is your friend in this case. I'm positive you'll spot your error right away. - Although it might very well be one of the executables that's writing to the file. Maybe change the name of the data file, see whether nsim or the new file contains the undesired numbers.

Comment: It was this REALLY weird bug causing problem. [link](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-bugs/2008-12/msg00292.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was because of this bug https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-bugs/2008-12/msg00292.html

Unit number 6 if used before write(*,*) in fortran writes to the file with 6 unit number.

SO this was a fortran file problem. It works as expected after changing it.